# NodeJS import only if not in production

Tags: node.js

Basically, I am using morgan to look at logs in developement. I have it under `--save-dev`. But in my `app.js` I use `const morgan = require('morgan');`. It runs fine on my local machine but I only use morgan depending on `NODE_ENV`. How can I make it that it doesnt raise a module not found exception in production? I will not be using it there so I have it in dev dependencies. Do I have to manually remove that line every time I deploy? Thanks :-)

Comment: I check the `NODE_ENV=='developement'` in an if statement then declare any development variables there. Or you can possibly use middleware that does the same thing kind of like a development config file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
if(NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  const morgan = require('morgan');
  app.use(morgan(...))
}
```

I just wrote a similar code snippet and ran into no issues.

Comment: how it affects build package? will 'morgan' be packaged into production package?

Answer (score 4):

You can just check the `NODE_ENV` environment variable in your code via the `process.env` object Node provides:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') const morgan = require('morgan');
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped. But this wont cause any exceptions right?

Comment: It would, actually, if you didn't wrap `app.use(morgan(...))` in the conditional as mentioned by therobinkim. However, you do need the `process.env` piece I mentioned here. Otherwise, `NODE_ENV` by itself would be an attempt to reference a var within your app, rather than from the environment.

Answer (score 1):

If the dependency is installed as a dev-dependency (should not get installed in production), then you can also use a try/catch block to conditionally import it:

```
let morgan
try {
    morgan = require('morgan')
} catch {}
morgan && app.use(morgan(...))
```

or:

```
try {
    const morgan = require('morgan')
    app.use(morgan(...))
} catch {}
```

This works, because the module does not exist in production and in this case require will throw an error

Answer (score 0):

In another instance of this question, someone mentioned create env variables on whichever platform you're using, whether it be Heroku, AWS, or digital ocean, and do something like this:

on heroku:

```
process.env.HEROKU = true
```

in app:

```
if(!process.env.HEROKU){
  privateData = require(url)
}

console.log(tryRequire.lastError())
```