# Using the source version instead of mimified when import lib with reactjs and npm

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, npm-install, react-highcharts

When I have an error on my code, I see the mimified version of the code in the devtool of the browser.When working with plain js, it was easy to link the src of the js file not mimified, but now I use npm install, package.json, and I dont know how to specify to get the complete source. Especially with highchart and highstock in reactjs react-hichart

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
import Highcharts from "highcharts/highcharts";
import exporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
```

Use:

```
import Highcharts from "highcharts/highcharts.src";
import exporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting.src";
```

Comment: thanks a lot, how to tell npm to get the mimified version when building ?

Comment: Hi @Phenix Glacé, Please check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48314120/nodejs-import-only-if-not-in-production Maybe you can use a similar approach.